# Calculate multiple field including null field

Tags: mysql

The calculation query only works when all the field were filled, it can correctly calculate 0 value but when there is *NULL* value, it doesnt returning any result

query :

```
SELECT
no,
price_1,
price_2,
price_3,
coalesce(round(price_1+price_2+price_3,2),0) AS total
from price_table
group by no
```

i use round to simplify the calculated result up to 2 decimal only

table :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| no | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 |             | no | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | total |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  |   0.10  |  NULL   |  NULL   |  result =>  | 1  |   0.10  |  NULL   |  NULL   |       |
| 2  |   0.20  |    0    |    0    |             | 2  |   0.20  |    0    |    0    |  0.20 |
| 3  |   0.30  |   0.20  |   0.50  |             | 3  |   0.30  |   0.20  |   0.50  |  1.00 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

result i looking for :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| no | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 |             | no | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | total |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  |   0.10  |  NULL   |  NULL   |  result =>  | 1  |   0.10  |  NULL   |  NULL   |  0.10 |
| 2  |   0.20  |    0    |    0    |             | 2  |   0.20  |    0    |    0    |  0.20 |
| 3  |   0.30  |   0.20  |   0.50  |             | 3  |   0.30  |   0.20  |   0.50  |  1.00 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++             ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

my question is on no.1 row , the total field is not showing any result, because the value of price_2 and/or price_3 is NULL, how to make the query to calculate all the price_  field including NULL value correctly?

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY`?  What is your question?

Comment: my question is on no.1 row , the total field is not showing any result, because the value of price_2 and/or price_3 is NULL, how to make the query to calculate all the price_  field including NULL value correctly?, if not using group by, it will only show 1 row on the query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `coalesce` on each column separately. Addition of `NULL`, and another value will evaluate to `NULL`, and you are likely to end up with 0 (since `coalesce(..., 0)` is what you specified) every time.

Try coalescing on each column in the calculation:

```
round(coalesce(price_1, 0) + coalesce(price_2, 0) + coalesce(price_3, 0),2) AS total
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you intended to use `COALESCE` on each of the three separate prices:

```
SELECT
    no,
    price_1,
    price_2,
    price_3,
    ROUND(COALESCE(price_1, 0) + COALESCE(price_2, 0) + COALESCE(price_3, 0), 2) AS total
FROM price_table;
```

Note: I see no reason to be using `GROUP BY` here at all, as you do not select any aggregates.  In fact, your current query is an invalid use of `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this seems to be an issue with how you're using null. The final answer will be null, as anything combined with null is still null. Correct comes down to your definition of correct here. What do you want to happen?

If you want mysql to treat nulls as zeros, then you'll need to use coalesce on each of the columns that you wish for this to happen on. In your query it would look like this:

```
    SELECT no,
   price_1,
   price_2,
   price_3,
   coalesce(round(
                        coalesce(price_1, 0) +
                        coalesce(price_2, 0) +
                        coalesce(price_3, 0)
                        2), 0) AS total
from price_table
```

I'm pretty sure the group by will throw an error, as you're not summing here. If you were doing sum(price_2), then the group by would be okay.

Comment: No, the `GROUP BY` would still _not_ have been OK, even selecting the sum, because the individual price columns do not also appear in the group by list.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. I'm saying if OP were to use aggregation functions over the prices, like sum(price_2) then it would be fine.

Comment: I'm saying this is a valid query: SELECT no,
   sum(price_1),
   sum(price_2),
   sum(price_3)
from price_table group by no

Comment: Agreed, that's valid :-)